# How to run nginx and IIS side by side in windows 8.1?

Tags: nginx, iis, web-server

Is it possible to run IIS and nginx side by side on windows 8.1 enterprise?

Right now I have installed both, but when I run WordPress for test, this is IIS that runs my WordPress.

I run nginx as well now, but how can I try it to run my test web site instead of IIS,
do I have to turn IIS off?

Comment: Giedrius please don't touch my question any more , don't edit theme please just answer if you know mine

Answer (score 3):

Run nginx on different port by changing your configuration (conf/nginx.conf) from:

```
listen       80;
```

to:

```
listen       8080;
```

Then, you can access it on port 8080:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: I did them all , wasn't effective Jakov , and try 7080 and 8080 , try 7081 on 8081 and some more else none of theme fix it , I install iis , nginx , apache all on the same server , now iis on 80 , apache on 8080 and nginx can't run

Comment: I also have another question , does it possible to run wordpress on nginx instead of apache ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run Wordpress (php) on nginx.

Comment: thanks dear jakov , do you know any way to uninstall nodejs hosting package from web platform installer , I install zoo holicon on web platform and then install nodejs hosting package from the zoo feed , but it's installation wasn't complete because of my sql express can't connect with sa user , now I want remove it and reinstall it again , if you know any way to remove it from web platform installer so help me

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that. Maybe you should post another question.

Comment: now I must create a new topick or wait here to some body may be answer it some day ? please help me if I must create a new topick to give my answer ?

Comment: If you have a question that is out of scope of the current topic, then yes, you should create new topic.